# Clear url in browser window using Java code

Tags: url

I am using navigate().to() method to navigate but new url is getting appended to old url as below, after executing navigate.to function thus resulting in 404 error

***https://www.google.co.in/www.yahoo.co.in***

Can anyone please help how should I get this to work?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver();
    fd.get("http://www.google.co.in");
    Thread.sleep(3000); 
    fd.navigate().to("www.yahoo.co.in");    
}
```

}

Comment: This can be done on other ways. are you restricted to use this `WebDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver();` only?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know how to achieve this using "navigate().to" method. But, can you also please tell me how to achieve this using alternate method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use `navigate().to()` but this an alternative solution.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

....

try {
    Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
    d.browse(new URI("http://www.google.co.in"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    d.browse(new URI("www.yahoo.co.in"));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1) use again `get()` method from the WebDriver to navigate to the new URL.

2) use `navigate().to()` method, but use fully qualified URL parameter. Eg. "https://www.google.com"
From the WebDriver javadoc: `@param url The URL to load. It is best to use a fully qualified URL`

The `navigate()` method is useful for using the context on the current web context. i.e. go back, forward.

Basically, the `get()` and `navigate().to()` do the same thing. I just tried both and they work. 
Reference: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/difference-between-webdriver-get-and-navigate